# U-SQL Gathering Files For Input - Taking a long time

Tags: u-sql

I am processing about 3600 files, distributed in 24 folders (one folder for each hour). **How fast *should* the process take to gather the files?** I am closing in on 1/2 hour. This is just our test system, I expected we will have 10X in production.

Comment: Update, the job failed at 25 minutes. Does anyone know what the max throughput is? This is just our test environment. I had only parallelism at 5.

Comment: What version of the tools are you using?  There was an improvement to input made in the [September release](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredatalake/2016/10/13/azure-data-lake-u-sql-september-2016-updates-outer-union-set-operations-by-name-file-and-partition-intrinsic-functions-and-more/) called 'Input File Set scales orders of magnitudes better (requires opt-in)' but apparently this requires opt-in.

Comment: Thanks wBob, I have requested the Opt-In!

Comment: I guess the latest release has implemented the File Set functionality, which I tried but couldn't get working.

Comment: The [October release note](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredatalake/2016/10/17/azure-data-lake-u-sql-october-2016-updates-deprecations-turn-into-errors-sampling-is-live-sharing-catalog-objects-across-adla-accounts-outputting-headers-and-more/) mentions the same feature but still states it is opt-in, so use the 'contact us' link on the note and get them to enable it for you.  Good luck!

Comment: The response was that it has been implemented. Perhaps I can't code. :)